# Where does google chrome store unpacked extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just lost all my changes to my google chrome plugin. However, the plugin is still running within the browser.

Where does Google Chrome store its cached copy of unpacked extensions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out that unpacked extensions are left in their original locations. Only packed extension get extracted to the places Alex.Piechowski mentioned.

Comment: Incorrect. Google does keep a cached copy in the folder I mentioned, but only temporally.

Comment: From the command line, to detect if an **unpacked** extension was installed, I was able to use
`fgrep -q /path/to/extension ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences||echo Extension not installed.` !

Answer (score 25):

I was able to find luck in:

Non-windows 7:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\<profile>\Extensions
```

-or-

Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\<profile>\Extensions
```

**EDIT**: You can go to "chrome://version/" (like a url) and it shows your "Profile Path". There you can find an "Extensions" folder which is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Note that "username" should be replaced with your username.

Comment: And apparently if you have multiple profiles set up it will look like this...  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile X\Default\Extensions  (with X being a number)

Comment: @StevenJenkins "\Default" should be taken out of that path.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux (OpenSuse 12.3), I managed to find all my installed extensions here:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/
```

It's important to first take note of the extension ID in case u wish to just copy a particular extension. For this, open `chrome://extensions/` in your browser, copy the id of the extension of interest, and find it's directory under the extensions directory given above.

Being able to locally save copies of extensions like this has helped me to continue using (and even modifying / hacking) on extension that were eventually removed from the Chrome Store by either their owners or Google.

Answer (score 4):

So I was debugging an extension I am building on Mac OS X and couldn't find the SQLite database in any of the standard locations.  It doesn't store the DB in the path where the extension files live.

Here's where I found my database when running an unpacked extension:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases/http_foobar.com_0/XX
```

-Eric

Answer (score 1):

User profiles are stored in [User Data Directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md) and it vary depending on the operating system.

The easiest way is to navigate to `chrome://version` and look for the *Profile Path* field.

> Example (Windows):
>
> - [Profile Path] C:\Users\Alice\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
> - [User Data Dir] C:\Users\Alice\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

Then Extensions are located under `Extensions/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

In windows:

Path: C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Extensions
(Here, you will not able to see extensions by name but it will be by extensions by Id. Extension Id you can get it from chrome→extension→Developer modes)

Or

Path:  C:\Documents and Settings\yourusername\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions

Or

Download Extension Source Locator. Give your username. It will list out all the extension with path details.